# Salesforce to Boomi callback

Tags: callback

We are doing a test path setup between sanbox boomi environment. In one of our process we had to test callback by initiating the call.But being new to this org I have no idea how to and where to check the call back is happening or not. what are the prerequisites to make a callback.

When the call back happens is. 
The external system updates some tables data in SFDC through Boomi and the sfdc system makes a callback based on the status and I need to check whether this call back has been done or not. where can I do a check.

Comment: This question is not clear and should be elaborated using [edit]. Which system makes what call and what is the expected result?

Comment: As per your comments I updated the question please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: How is the callback done? APEX Http Callout? Workflow outbound messaging?  something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call back is going through o/b MSG, I was able to find the call back in outbound message queue.